How to do a VLOOKUP in an HTML form with Google script?
I am trying to achieve VLOOKUP within HTML using Google Apps Script and JavaScript.
We have Google site in which a HTML form is designed with Google Apps Script. User will have to enter their ID value in ID field and their name will be auto populated in the name field.
Only one Google spreadsheet file is used. One tab is to receive the user's entry another tab got the list of ID and name of the users.
Following are my tries:

Google apps script:
function FindName(uin) {
  var data=Udata.getRange('A2:B').getValues();
  var valA=uin;
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][0]==valA){break} ; 
     }
Logger.log(data[nn][1]);
return (data[nn][1]);
}


JavaScript (Updated): With this update I am getting undefined value in the name field:
function fetchName(){
  var userId = document.getElementById("uin").value; 
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = google.script.run.FindName(userId);  
}


HTML form code:
<div class="mb-1">
  <label for="uin" class="form-label">Enter  uin:</label>
  <input type="text" id="uin" name="uin" class="form-control form-control-sm" onkeyup="fetchName()" required> 
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
  <label for="Name" class="form-label"> Name:</label>    
  <input type="text" id="Name1" name="Name1" class="form-control form-control-sm" required> 

  <p>Welcome <span id="Name"></span></p>

</div>



But onkeyup the name never gets populated.
When I feed in the ID value in Google script manually and check with debugging the name appears in the log, but in HTML form it doesn't work.

Have updated the javascript which now gives me 'undefined' as the user name. Hope I am nearing a solution. But unable to make that undefined as username from the google sheet file. Anyone please help!

Questions should not be edited to include changes recommended in answers, which might invalidate the answer. If you have a follow-up question, post a new question instead. On the other hand, please bear in mind that questions on this site should be about using a web app, like the https://script.google.com. Questions about programming, are better suited for [so].

Yes I am asking for google script codes only. How can it be invalid?
I've updated the question with my own tried codes lastly not kept the one which is recommended.

The question is not about Google Apps Script classes and methods or using the Google Apps Script online editor. The answer and the edits you have are focused on client-side code, that makes the question off-topic.

The success handler is not constructed properly. Its first argument contains the return value from the server-side function. Use this:
function fetchName(name) {
  console.log(`fetchName() received the name '${name}'`);
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = name;
}

See withSuccessHandler.
Also see Apps Script debugging and How to debug small programs.

Modified the code to like this
function fetchName(UName) {
var uin = document.getElementById("uin").value;
var Uname = FindName(uin);
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = UName;
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchName).FindName();
Still not working :( onkeyup name is not appearing.

Updated the question. But without the google scripts function can we find the name with your code?

The question doesn't show the code I gave you. The version of fetchName() in the question overwrites its argument, erasing the result retrieved from the server and rendering the whole client-server trip pointless. Use the code in the answer to fix that.

... hmm.. By replacing the code with your code of Javascript too didn't fetch any name. If I pass the 'uin' value as hardcoded in googlescript, the logger shows the name on debug. But with the Javascript I am unable to make it happen in html form field :(

Edited the answer to add console.log(). See the web browser's JavaScript console to confirm that name is returned correctly by the server side. See the resources I listed to learn how to debug.

doubleunary,
I thank you for your continued support. But onkeyup="fetchName(this.value)" populates the ID value in the name field whereas I need the "name" value against that ID, name must be taken from the XL sheet and auto-populate in the name field against the ID value entered. - glad that the field now shows some value with your javascript - but not the required result.

Is my google script wrong? Or is there any direct Java script to fetch the name value against ID value entered in html form after checking with the googlesheet tab data?
